# changing time series and corresponding data

Tags: matlab

I would like to change my time vector (T1) and its corresponding data (Data1) to a new time vector (T2) and include Nan's in the corresponding data (Data2).
For example:-

```
T1                        Data1
01-Sep-2007 00:00:30       0.01
01-Sep-2007 00:01:30       0.02
01-Sep-2007 00:02:30       0.03
01-Sep-2007 00:03:30       0.05
01-Sep-2007 00:04:29       0.08
01-Sep-2007 00:07:30       0.09
01-Sep-2007 00:09:29       0.05
```

I would like to change T1 and Data1 to a new vector T2 and Data2 which I would like to have it as shown below:-

```
T2                        Data2
01-Sep-2007 00:00:00       0.01
01-Sep-2007 00:01:00       0.02
01-Sep-2007 00:02:00       0.03
01-Sep-2007 00:03:00       0.05
01-Sep-2007 00:04:00       0.08
01-Sep-2007 00:05:00       NaN
01-Sep-2007 00:06:00       NaN
01-Sep-2007 00:07:00       0.09
01-Sep-2007 00:08:00       NaN
01-Sep-2007 00:09:00       0.05
```

Please could someone help me regarding this, as i dont know a method which could do it i MATLAB.Any help will be greatly appreciated !!
Thanks in advance.. Shital

Comment: Which data type is `T1`? It can't be a vector. Is it a cell array containing strings?

Comment: I change T1 to Matlab date by using datenum.

Comment: If you had `01-Sep-2007 00:07:45`, would that data value get assigned to `01-Sep-2007 00:07:00` or to `01-Sep-2007 00:08:00`? Also, is it possible that you have `01-Sep-2007 00:07:00` and `01-Sep-2007 00:07:10`, and what would you do in that case?

Comment: To make easy to understand I have shown T1 and T2 as string.. otherwise in my script i use Datenum to convert the string to serial date number

Comment: I doubt that makes it easier to understand :-)

Comment: I donot have 01-Sep-2007 00:07:45.. My time is every one minute..e.g. 01-Sep-2007 00:07:30 ; 01-Sep-2007 00:08:30 etc.. but sometimes the instrument records 01-Sep-2007 00:09.29 etc.. I want to change all time to 01-Sep-2007 00:07:00;01-Sep-2007 00:08:00 ;01-Sep-2007 00:09:00 etc..

Comment: I ahve done in my script                                       start = datenum('01-Sept-2007 00:00:00');
stop = datenum('30-Sept-2007 23:59:00');
T2 = (start:1./1440:stop)'; but then how to synchronize the corresponding Data1 to the new T2 is what I am unable to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have your `t1` and `data`

```
>> t1, data1

t1 =

01-Sep-2007 00:00:30
01-Sep-2007 00:01:30
01-Sep-2007 00:02:30
01-Sep-2007 00:03:30
01-Sep-2007 00:04:29
01-Sep-2007 00:07:30
01-Sep-2007 00:09:29


data1 =

    0.0100
    0.0200
    0.0300
    0.0500
    0.0800
    0.0900
    0.0500
```

First you want to turn `t1` into a datenum

```
>> t1 = datenum(t1);
```

and then round it to the previous minute

```
>> dt = 1 / 24 / 60;
>> t1_rounded = floor(t1 / dt) * dt;
```

Now you can create your `t2` vector

```
>> t2 = (min(t1_rounded):dt:max(t1_rounded))';
```

and use the second output of the `histc` command to match up the indexes -

```
>> [~, index] = histc(t1, [t2; Inf]);
```

The final `Inf` catches anything that falls off the end of your `t2` vector. Finally, you just create the new data vector to be full of `NaN`s and assign to it.

```
>> data2 = NaN(size(t2));
>> data2(index) = data1;
```

so your result is

```
>> datestr(t2), data2

ans =

01-Sep-2007 00:00:00
01-Sep-2007 00:01:00
01-Sep-2007 00:02:00
01-Sep-2007 00:03:00
01-Sep-2007 00:04:00
01-Sep-2007 00:05:00
01-Sep-2007 00:06:00
01-Sep-2007 00:07:00
01-Sep-2007 00:08:00
01-Sep-2007 00:09:00


data2 =

    0.0100
    0.0200
    0.0300
    0.0500
    0.0800
       NaN
       NaN
    0.0900
       NaN
    0.0500
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not getting the Data2 as expected.. what i get is Data2 = [Nan;0.01;0.02;NaN;0.03;0.05;NaN; etc].

Comment: Did you do all the steps in the same order as in my answer?

Comment: When it does the t1_round, the floor or the round command sometimes duplicates the time..

Comment: The answer makes the assumption that your data are roughly equally spaced, by around 1 minute. If that's not true, then you won't get the correct answer (but I can't possibly know that, because I can't see your data). If you follow the steps I showed, with the data you specified in your question, then it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I rewrote my script as per your instructions.. and now it works fine.. Thanks a lot  for your great help !!

Comment: sorry to bother again.. but i tried using your method for another set of data now.. Unfortunately it doesnot work. The index is being duplicated many times down the column and therefore doesnot result in Data2 as expected..any help would be greatly appreciated !!Thanks

Comment: Start a new question for it (and explain what the problem is as clearly as possible).

Answer (score 0):

So your first step is to round `T1` to the nearest 30 seconds (probably like this: `round(T1/dt)*dt` but it depends on your data). Then you can generate `T2` like this:

```
dt = 1/(2*60*24);
T2 = min(T1_rounded):dt:max(T1_rounded);
```

or most likely

```
T2 = (T1_rounded(1):dt:T1_rounded(end))';
```

strictly speaking you will want to round off `T2` again at this point to avoid possible (actually likely) floating point arithmetic errors in the `ismember` step ahead...

```
T2 = round(T2/dt)*dt
```

now initialise `Data2` to be the right size but full of `NaN`s:

```
Data2 = NaN(size(T2))
```

lastly find the right indexes:

```
ind = ismember(T2, T1_rounded)
```

and apply them:

```
Data2(ind) = Data1
```

Comment: Thanks  for your reply.. but there is a problem..My Data2 should not be of the same size as Data1. That is because Data1 corresponds to old time T1 which has missing timesteps or gaps.. which I intend to clear by using T2 and adding NaNs to the corresponding Data2 ...so the 3rd last step doesnot work..

Comment: @user3876557 sorry it was meant to be `T2`

Comment: thanks but as I said The Data1 size is not same as Data2. so the last step doesnot work unfortunately.

Comment: @user3876557 the last step only requires that `Data1` is the size of `nnz(ind)`. This answer is identical to Chris Taylor's answer except for using `ismember` instead of `histc`...

Comment: Thanks for your help Dan.. The round command however was duplicating the time column.. The floor command worked fine for me.. thanks !!